# Is it possible to set custom CPU throttling in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, cpu, throttling

I am using Google Chrome 63.

In DevTools in **Performance** tab there are three CPU throttling settings: "No throttling", "4x slowdown" and "6x slowdown".

Is it possible to set custom throttling, for example "20x slowdown"? It could be via setting some flag in **chrome.exe** file or programmatically via NodeJS library.

I found that Lighthouse library has kind of [helpful function](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-lighthouse/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.lighthouse.emulation.enableCPUThrottling) but if I change the default value inside it (**CPU_THROTTLE_METRICS** seems to be equal to 4) from 4 to (for example) 20 and run it, how can I be sure it really is 20x slowed down?

Also, I would like to know, if it is possible to do such simulated "slow down" to the GPU in similar way?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 12):

Custom values for `Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate` can be set right in Chrome, but you need to open a Dev Tools window on the Dev Tools window to change the setting programatically.

1. Open Dev Tools; make sure it is detached (open in its own window).
2. Open Dev Tools again on the Dev Tools window from step 1 using the key combination Cmd-Opt-i (Mac) or Ctrl-Shift-i (Windows).
3. Run the following in the Console tab:

   ```
   let Main = await import('./devtools-frontend/front_end/entrypoints/main/main.js');
   await Main.MainImpl.sendOverProtocol('Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate', {rate: 40});
   ```

This example will throttle Chrome performance by 40x. NOTE: Passing 1 for `rate` turns off throttling.

The first Dev Tools window created in Step 1 may be re-docked after creating the second Dev Tools window.

Comment: This gives an error for me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendOverProtocol')`

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to import main.js to avoid the error:
`let Main = await import('./devtools-frontend/front_end/entrypoints/main/main.js'); await Main.MainImpl.sendOverProtocol('Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate', {rate: 40});`

Comment: For Edge, `let Main = await import('./entrypoints/main/main.js');` has to be used instead

Comment: This fails for me with the error `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Comment: Got `Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate' wasn't found` now, as of Mar 8, 2024 on Chrome `Version 122.0.6261.94 (Official Build) (arm64)`

Answer (score 4):

Lighthouse uses `Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate` command in the Chrome DevTools Protocol:

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation#method-setCPUThrottlingRate

You can monitor the protocol this way:

https://umaar.com/dev-tips/166-protocol-monitor/

You'll see this command in the protocol log when you switch with the throttling setting in the performance panel.

If you're asking how to be sure if it works - here is the implementation from Chromium source code:

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/scheduler/util/thread_cpu_throttler.h#L21

> `// This class is used to slow down the main thread for
>   // inspector "cpu throttling". It does it by spawning an
>   // additional thread which frequently interrupts main thread
>   // and sleeps.`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Up-to-date link for the throttler: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/scheduler/public/thread_cpu_throttler.h

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use `cpulimit`

```sh
sudo apt-get install cpulimit
# -l 5 means 5% , or 20x slowdown
cpulimit -l 5 chromium-browser
```

Comment: This will throttle the entire browser and devtools instead of just the tab.